# Exception in "with" block blanks file opened for writing

Tags: python, file

This simple code

```
# This code will BLANK the file 'myfile'!
with open('myfile', 'w') as file:
    raise Exception()
```

rather than merely throwing an exception, **deletes all data in "myfile",** although no actual write operation is even attempted.

This is dangerous to say the least, and certainly not how other languages treat such situations.

How I can prevent this? Do I have to handle every possible exception in order to be certain that the target file will not be blanked by some unforeseen condition? Surely there must be a standard pattern to solve this problem. And, above all: What is happening here in the first place?

Comment: That is because "w" or "write" mode will by default truncate the file first. This is done during the time when "open(..)" happens.

Comment: You are mistaken, every language I know will truncate a file by default when you open it for writing, regardless of how much (if any) you then write to it.

Comment: This behavior has nothing to do with Python. It is the defined semantics of the `open` system call under POSIX/Unix/Linux, OS X and Windows. If you want to change this behavior in Python, you have to drop down to the OS level with [os.open](http://linux.die.net/man/2/open) specifically omitting the `O_TRUNC` constant from *mode*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are opening a file for writing. It is *that simple action* that blanks the file, regardless of what else you do with it. From the [`open()` function documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open):

> `'w'`
>   open for writing, **truncating the file first**

Emphasis mine. In essence, the file is empty because you didn't write anything to it, not because you opened it.

Postpone opening the file to a point where you actually have data to write if you don't want this to happen. Writing a list of strings to a file is not going to cause exceptions *at the Python level*.

Alternatively, write to a *new* file, and rename (move) it afterwards to replace the original. Renaming a file as left to the OS.

Comment: And if I have data to write but an error occurs during writing?

Comment: @user4395564: then you still have already emptied the file. If you ensured you have data ready to write then at least that exception won't be caused by your Python program; what is left is premature shutdown (of the program or the machine) or disk-related problems (no more disk space, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

The statement `open('myfile', 'w')` ***will*** delete all the contents on execution i.e. truncate the file.

If you want to retain the lines you have to use `open('myfile', 'a')`. Here the `a` option is for `append`.

Comment: But then the OP won't be *replacing* the information if no exception takes place.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Isn't the question a little unclear as to what the OP wants to do after the `open` call.

Comment: No, but appending is a very different kind of operation. Better to write to a new file and have the OS replace the old.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Is my answer completely wrong then? Or should I just edit the append part?

Comment: It is a different interpretation from mine; I think it is incorrect but I'm also not infallible. :-P

Answer (score 0):

Opening a file for writing erases the contents. Best way to avoid lost of data, not only in case of exceptions, also computer shutdown, etc. is to create a new temporary file and rename the file to the original name, when everything is done.

```
yourfile = "myfile"
try:
    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(dir=os.path.dirname(yourfile) or '.', delete=False) as output:
        do_something()
except Exception:
    handle_exception()
else:
    os.rename(output.name, yourfile)
```